# Возможно ли инициализировать Moxy MvpPresenter в RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, moxy

Возможно ли сделать inject MvpPresenter в RecyclerView Adapter или библиотека позволяет делать это только для фрагмента или активности? И насколько правильно так делать с точки зрения архитектуры?
Код адаптера:

```
public class ElementsRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ElementsRecyclerAdapter.ElementsViewHolder> {

    List<Elements> elementsList;

    public ElementsRecyclerAdapter(List<Elements> elementsList){
        this.elementsList = elementsList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ElementsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_elements, parent,false);
        return new ElementsViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ElementsViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.elementName.setText(elementsList.get(position).getName());
        holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    holder.elementsAdapterPresenter.deleteElement(elementsList.get(position));
                }
                catch (NullPointerException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return elementsList.size();
    }

    public static class ElementsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements ElementsAdapterView{

        TextView elementName;
        Button updateButton;
        Button deleteButton;

        @InjectPresenter
        ElementsAdapterPresenter elementsAdapterPresenter;

        public ElementsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            elementName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.element_name);
            updateButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.update_element);
            deleteButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_element);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpdate(Elements element) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDelete(Integer id) {

        }
    }
}
```

При дебаге `elementsAdapterPresenter = null`

Comment: не надо в адаптер инжектить презентер. в адаптере вы просто обрабатываете клик. а что будет происходить при нажатии описываете во фрагменте или активити 
через интерфейс  https://stackoverflow.com/a/58022089/8389574

Answer (score 0):

В адаптер можно инжектнуть презентер, но нужно понимать специфику данного решения. С точки зрения архитектуры  в этом ничего страшного нет и это можно делать, но это используется в очень редких ситуациях, что может наталкнуть других разработчиков на мысли "А зачем?".

В каком случае имеет смысл делать inject презентера в ViewHolder? В том случае, если очень много логики по отображению каких либо данных на элементе, есть определенные случаи, сейчас приведу пример:

У нас есть экран со списком профилей пользователей, и допустим есть общая модель профиля включающая в себя базовую информацию : "Имя,Фамилия,Статус", а для того чтобы получить картинку профиля нужно дергать новый зарос. Такие инетерсные и специфичные решения могут встречаться в библиотеках.  И запрос дергается для каждой карточки(каждого ViewHolder) в этом случае имеет смысл использовать инжект презентера во ViewHolder, в остальных других случаях как написали в комментариях лучше работать через интерфейс.